# Converting enthalpy from J/g to kJ/mol

Tags: unit-conversion

On some books I found values of enthalpy in J/g, on other books in kJ/mol. How could I convert  enthalpy from J/g to kJ/mol?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know the [*molar mass*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molar_mass) $M$ ($\mathrm{g/mol}$) of the material (substance).

Say the Enthalpy in $\mathrm{J/g}$ is $H_w$, then the Enthalpy in $\mathrm{J/mol}$ is $H_M$, with:

$$H_M=H_w\times M$$

Divide by $1000$ to convert to $\mathrm{kJ/mol}$.

If the material is *not a pure substance* (i.e. a mixture) then you need to [calculate a molar average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molar_mass#Average_molar_mass_of_mixtures) for $M$ of the material.